# jQuery Mouse events - how to fire multiple times

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create something my boss like's to call an "interactive infographic" which is pretty much like a quiz.

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how I can get my jQuery events to fire multiple times? Do I need to use a loop? Pretty much I have a mouseenter and mouseleave event but they only fire once.

Also I am having the problem that my h2 elements "jilt down" when the tick appears.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.user-answer-a').hide();
$('.user-answer-b').hide();
//    slide in from right
$('.left-side-container h2').addClass('animated slideInRight');
$('.answer-container h2').addClass('animated slideInRight');
//    show tick on hover
$('.right-side-container-top').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $('.user-answer-a').show();
    $('.user-answer-a').addClass('animated zoomIn');
});
$('.right-side-container-top').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $('.user-answer-a').show();
    $('.user-answer-a').addClass('animated zoomOut');
});
$('.right-side-container-bottom').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $('.user-answer-b').show();
    $('.user-answer-b').addClass('animated zoomIn');
});
$('.right-side-container-bottom').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $('.user-answer-b').show();
    $('.user-answer-b').addClass('animated zoomOut');
});
});
```

Take a look at my codepen [here](http://codepen.io/erayner/pen/qReEJm)

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: On `mousenter` event you have a `function`. That function can do as much code as you want it to. It can build an entire website. It can even programatically trigger other mouse events, though some browsers don't particularily agree with this technique and either block it or alert the user (you don't want that). All you need to do is put everything you want your function to do inside it. Same goes for `mouseleave`, of course.

Comment: youre not undoing the things you do in your mouseenter in youre mouseleave.  And vice versa.

Comment: jQuery has two options to create an event listener. on() is an active listener, so you can click it how much you want and it fires the event. one() just fires it once for one page loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're going to do this step by step.

- it's best to add the class **animated** to the top and bottom
  containers in HTML so we don't have to add it in JS multiple times.

We don't want to repeat our code 1000 times so we put repeated code
   in functions

```
function showA() {
    $('.user-answer-a').removeClass('zoomOut').addClass('zoomIn');
  }

 function hideA() {
    $('.user-answer-a').removeClass('zoomIn').addClass('zoomOut');
  }

 function showB() {
    $('.user-answer-b').removeClass('zoomOut').addClass('zoomIn');
  }

function hideB() {
    $('.user-answer-b').removeClass('zoomIn').addClass('zoomOut');
  }
```

Now we can call these functions in our Event Listeners. I used zoomIn/zoomOut instead of show and hide since the latter can not show animation Final

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.user-answer-a').toggleClass('zoomOut');
    $('.user-answer-b').toggleClass('zoomOut');
    //    slide in from right
    $('.left-side-container h2').addClass('animated slideInRight');
    $('.answer-container h2').addClass('animated slideInRight');
    //    show tick on hover
    $('.right-side-container-top').on('mouseenter', function () {
        showA();
      hideB();
    }).on('mouseleave', function () {
        hideA();
    });
    $('.right-side-container-bottom').on('mouseenter', function () {
        hideA();
      showB(); 
    }).on('mouseleave', function () {
        hideB();
    });

  function showA() {
    $('.user-answer-a').removeClass('zoomOut').addClass('zoomIn');
  }

  function hideA() {
    $('.user-answer-a').removeClass('zoomIn').addClass('zoomOut');
  }

  function showB() {
    $('.user-answer-b').removeClass('zoomOut').addClass('zoomIn');
  }

  function hideB() {
    $('.user-answer-b').removeClass('zoomIn').addClass('zoomOut');
  }

});
```

*About the tick I didn't understand what you meant*

Comment: dude you're amazing. thanks a lot for your help. :) you'll make a great tutor one day. Ill figure the tick by myself. Thanks again